# Why does the code hang when calling cancelInquiry in Java to cancel, a Bluetooth inquiry, on some Nokia phones?

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, nokia-s40, synchronized-block

i have a problem on Nokia devices having S40 (but not on S60).
the problem is this:
when you call the discoveryAgent's cancelInquiry method from within a synchronized block,
it hangs. it is actually supposed to call back inquiryCompleted. the code simply freezes- never enters
the inquiryCompleted method.
if the same thing is done but not from within a synchronized block - everything works. The problem is that i need the block to be synchronized so that everything in it is executed atomically in a multi-threaded app.

This is what my DiscoveryListener looks like:

```
public class DeviceDiscoverer implements DiscoveryListener {
   private Object thisCannotBeInterruptedByOtherBlocksLikeIt=new Object();
   private boolean stiiInCycle;
   private DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent;

   public boolean cancel() { //called from some controller in mid discovery
      //synchronized(thisCannotBeInterruptedByOtherBlocksLikeIt) //problem when this is uncommented
      {
         if (stillInCycle) {
             //<some logic>
             discoveryAgent.cancelInquiry(this);
             //<more logic>
         }
      }
   }
   public void inquiryCompleted(int inquiryStatus) { //this is a callback in response to cancel or normal ending
      Beeper.beep(); //this makes the phone make a sound
   }

   // <some irrelevant methods here. some have synchronized blocks like the one above>
}
```

when you run the above code, on both s40 and s60, with the synchronized statement commented out, 
and call the cancel() method, the inquiryCompleted method is immediately called and you hear the beep.
BUT, if you uncomment the synchronized statement, you hear the beep on S60, but on S40 (at least on 5th edition fp1), the inquiryCompleted is never called! (when i placed the beep stmt just before calling the discoveryAgent's cancelInquiry it beeped. when i placed it after that call, it didn't get there. that's because the call does not
return until it calls inquiryCompleted and that call doesn't happen)

what is the problem? if it's a bug in the impl'n of the cancelInquiry of S40, how do i get around it?
i have to synchronize because things are done in parallel (for example my code may start an inquiry
and then, may cancel it. at the time that it is cancelled the startInquiry may be running, deviceDiscovered may be running, inquiryCompleted may be running, and of course in parallel with any of these, the incoming cancelInquiry
may be running.

i tried to separate the inquiryCompleted into another listener instance, in  other words, instead of calling
discoveryAgent.cancelInquiry(this) i called discoveryAgent.cancelInquiry(anotherInstance) hoping that
the inquiryCompleted in the 'anotherInstance' would be called but no, it hangs that way as well.

any suggestions?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not fond of this approach, but, as you can not use synchronized... What about a busy waiting loop? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_wait

You may try the code below:

```
    private Thread cancelThread;

    public boolean cancel() {
        synchronized(this) {
            while (cancelThread != null) {
                try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            cancelThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }

        // do your stuff

        cancelThread = null; // before return
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i understand the concept that you are suggesting, and i'm not fond of busy loops either, but i any case, i don't understand your meaning: what does the synchronized(this) accomplish? if it's purpose is to control access to cancelThread, it does not do that when it sets it to null. also it blocks all methods of the instance. i synch on an object so that other methods of the instance can execute freely. and i synch for atomicity of the block.